# How to validate the BGcolor in a webpage using Robot framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

I don't know how to validate the bg color in a webpage using robot framwork.

Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Welcome to [so] where we help those with the technical difficulties they face. Because this is not aimed to be a traditional forum we do have expectations that are formulated in [ask]. At the very least we expect some effort to have been spent on your part. By showing us the code you're working and your observations of the result we are better informed of what you've tried and can build on those examples in our anwsers. It typically generates better answers tailerored to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

u can try to execute following js script which should return RGB code for your tag

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('your_tag_id'),null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Comment: This is javascript, not python.

Comment: You can execute javaScript using  [Execute JavaScript](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript) keyword and get it output.